# Adding distinct blocks of K values together in a vector

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a vector called,

```
A= [2;3;4;5;6;7];
```

I want to introduce a variable called `K`. If the value of 'K' is `1` then I will get the same as the output. However, if the value of `K` is `2` then I am expecting the output vector to be:

```
output= [2+3;4+5;6+7];
```

If the value of `K` is `3` then my output will be:

```
output= [2+3+4;5+6+7];
```

In addition, we can safely assume that the total number of elements in `A` are evenly divisible by `K`.  Maybe this is a silly question for an expert, but I would really appreciate the guidance in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the number of elements in `A` is divisible by `K`, you could use some reshaping and summation, like so -

```
sum(reshape(A,K,[]),1)
```

**Sample runs**

Input :

```
A =
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
```

Run #1 :

```
>> K = 2;
>> reshape(A,K,[])
ans =
     2     4     6
     3     5     7
>> sum(reshape(A,K,[]),1)
ans =
     5     9    13
```

Run #2 :

```
>> K = 3;
>> reshape(A,K,[])
ans =
     2     5
     3     6
     4     7
>> sum(reshape(A,K,[]),1)
ans =
     9    18
```

---

If the number of elements in A is not divisible by K, you could use [`vec2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html) from `Communications System Toolbox`, like so -

```
sum(vec2mat(A,K).',1) %// OR sum(vec2mat(A,K),2)
```

**Sample runs**

```
A =
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
```

Run #1 :

```
>> K = 2;
>> vec2mat(A,K).'
ans =
     2     4     6     8
     3     5     7     9
>> sum(vec2mat(A,K).',1)
ans =
     5     9    13    17
```

Run #2 :

```
>> K = 3;
>> vec2mat(A,K).'
ans =
     2     5     8
     3     6     9
     4     7     0
>> sum(vec2mat(A,K).',1)
ans =
     9    18    17
```

Comment: Yes "A" is always divisible by "K". You are right reshaping is a good idea. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks, just tested yours, which works too! :)

Comment: @BruceDenby Consider accepting one of the solutions that worked best for you?

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to perform convolution with the kernel as being all 1s and the kernel's length is `K`, but the intricacy is that you **skip over** every `K` elements in the result because this uses a sliding window to sum elements together.

Simply put:

```
output = conv(A, ones(K,1), 'valid');
output = output(1:K:end);
```

The nice thing about this approach is that you don't have to assume that the total length of `A` is evenly divisible by `K`.

## Sample runs

```
>> A = [2 3 4 5 6 7]'; %'
>> K = 2;
>> output = conv(A, ones(K,1), 'valid');
>> output = output(1:K:end)

output =

     5
     9
    13

>> K = 3;
>> output = conv(A, ones(K,1), 'valid');
>> output = output(1:K:end)

output =

     9
    18
```

Comment: I did not know about this before. It is very much helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: @BruceDenby You're very welcome :) I would have used `sum/reshape` myself, but it wasn't known if the length of `A` is divisible by `K` until your comment to Divakar.  I assumed it wasn't, so this is where my answer came from.  Either way, I'm glad that his solution worked!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, which works even if the size of `A` is not a multiple of `K`, is to define a grouping index and apply [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
result = accumarray(ceil((1:numel(A)).'/K),A(:));
```

Comment: @rayryeng So does yours! :-)